# IE 11 doesn't firing the error event on invalid video format

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This is a weird problem with IE 11 but I have no option. Here's the thing;

I have an HTML `<video>` tag to show an MP4 video and it's tested, it works but the server is configured to serve cached versions with Redis (i can't change that, is on the server of the client). When the cache expires (eg: you reload the browser or just let time pass for 3 minutes) you can't reproduce the video and need a refresh; for this purpose, I make a script:

**Note: this is Vue**:

```
async videoErrorHandler() { 
    const video = document.querySelector('video'); 
    const source = document.querySelector('source'); 
    await this.$store.dispatch('getDocFromNet'); 
    this.retries++; 
    if (this.retries > 5) { 
        source.removeEventListener('error', this.videoErrorHandler); 
        video.removeEventListener('play', this.videoErrorHandler); 
         return false; 
    }
    video.load(); 
    video.removeEventListener('play', this.videoErrorHandler); 
    video.play(); 
    return true; 
}
```

**And the attachments:**

```
updated() { 
   const video = document.querySelector('video'); 
    const source = document.querySelector('source'); 
    if (this.retries === 0) { 
        source.addEventListener('error', this.videoErrorHandler); 
        video.addEventListener('play', this.videoErrorHandler); 
}
```

The problem here is pretty simple. When the cache returns invalid, the video script enters in a reload loop and ask for a new valid URL and save it to the store.

Well, in IE the `error` event is not fired. Chrome, Firefox, even Edge is working, checking the DOM element events attached on the `<source>` tag, the `error` event is bound but no matter what, in IE is never fired.

**Note:** in the first load of the page, the video is accessible and reproducible, but after 3 minutes reload, it just stops working and shows me an "invalid source" in the video box.

Comment: Have you used F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console? You can debug the `update()` function to see if it goes into `if(this.retries === 0)` in IE. And with only the above code snippet, I can't reproduce the issue on my side. It would be better if you could provide [a simple sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which helps to reproduce the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yep I debugged the update() and yep, `this.retries` is working, let me see if i can work in a minimal example. This resources are not accesible out of a virtual machine.